# Is migration from Trinity to Firefly still possible?

Tags: wallet, chrysalis, firefly

Because of the pandemic, iota was not high priority.
Missed the seed migration period. We have firefly.
We have Iota on Trinity still Now, what can we do?

Answer (score 3):

You did not miss anything. You can still migrate. https://blog.iota.org/firefly-token-migration/

Answer (score 1):

Calm down and don't over-react. Everything is fine.

As MK pointed out: if you had your tokens on Trinity, you did not miss out. The migration period to Firefly is still open, and you are not alone - only [66% of tokens migrated to Firefly so far](https://chrysalis.iota.org/status).

The CURL to KERL migration period from the old IOTA Light Wallet (which started mid-2017) closed recently, but in case you would have missed it, you could not have used Trinity.